# Fill a tableView with two arrays in two custom cells Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview

I can't find a way to fill my tableView without using section like Periscope do in its app on the live (I suppose they do like that).
I have two arrays: one for the comments and another one for the user joined the room.

I want the same result like Periscope app in the photos below:

[image]

You can see in this photo the first cell is for the comment and the second cell is for someone just enter in the room (est là = joined), Bruninette is her nickname.

[image]

Then you can see some others users comments this live and the cell with Bruninette joined are go up to the first cell visible

I think Periscope use 2 arrays and they are mixed in the tableView.
Someone can help me with how can I do the same thing.
Thank you very much.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var socket: SocketIOClient!
var comments: [Comment] = []
var joinerArray: [Joiner] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    socket.on("comment") {[weak self] data ,ack in
        let comment = Comment(dict: data[0] as! [String: AnyObject])
        self?.comments.append(comment)
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    socket.on("joiner") {[weak self] data ,ack in
        let joiner = Joiner(dict: data[0] as! [String: AnyObject])
        self?.joinerArray.append(joiner)
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.socket.emit("joiner", [
        "roomKey": self.room.key,
        "name": Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName])
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string == "\n" {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        if let text = textField.text , text != "" {
                    self.socket.emit("comment", [
                        "roomKey": self.room.key,
                        "text": text,
                        "name": Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName,
                        "photo": userImg])
                }
        textField.text = ""
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count + joinerArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row < comments.count {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentaireTableViewCell
        cell.comment = comments[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "joinCell", for: indexPath) as! JoinTableViewCell
        let index = indexPath.row - comments.count
        cell.joiner = joinerArray[index]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single array for both comments and room entry. And use different cells with different identifiers for each. And in tableview's cellforrow data-source method check for the type of data and use corresponding cellidentifier to get appropriate cells.

Comment: Can you add some code for how to implement that? Because for comments I have an array of type Comment with 3 attributes (name, photoURL and text) and for joiners I have an array of type Joiner with name in attribute